# Windows Server 2003 R2 no contact on Hyper-V Windows Server 2008 R2  Standar edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, hyper-v

I have installed  W2k3 R2 VM, since it had at start no network detected i added a legacy network adapter and installed intergration services. Now by recommendations on the comments of ths question I change the legacy network adapter to a tradicional virtual network adapter.

The server is used as DNS and a Domain Controller.
Users are working as intended with no problems.

Still i get the "Heartbeat: No contact" message but the icon shows the activity of the server.

What did i do wrong ?

P.S.

As i noticed, i cannot install intergration services as it retruns an OS icompatibility error and update via Windows Update is not possible returning a '0x80072EFE windows update error' 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To start you should not use the legacy network adapter if you don't really need. ¿Do you really need it? 
If not change to a normal network adapter for continue. You can accomplish this task using this procedure http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956895(WS.10).aspx

Comment: i only used it because the installation of the server did not found any network so through some reading articles i found that when this happens a legacy network should be installed, and after that the server found network. the server is  x86

Comment: No @Cmosk. Windows Server 2003 r2 is capable to work with normal NICS, legacy are not nececesary and are very slow.

Comment: i have unistalled the legacy card but after that no network again on the server. So i have reinstalled it again. Still no contact though

Comment: Now, using *devmgmt.msc* do a scan for new hardware and wait if it detects someting.  After that Please add to your question the snapshot of all your devices using *devmgmt.msc*

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/files/3424288662/Snapshots.rar a snapshot using devmgmt.msc

Comment: Thank you but I did not explain right. When I mean a snapshot, I mean what you see on your pc. Like a picture of your screen. In fact an Hyper-V snapshot without the parent hardisk is useless.

Comment: ok. sorry abt the missunderstaning. I had the same question but i thought you'd had some 'pixie dust' to mount that Snapshot :). I added to the main question the ScreenShot you wanted.

Comment: Ohh. I think i know whats is happening. @Cmosk one last thing, please add a snapshot of running *winver*.exe

Comment: ok . i posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this issue because you are running an unssoported for Hyper-v version of Windows Server 2003 R2. You are running Windows Server 2003 R2 SP1.

You should install the Service Pack 2. Then install the Hyper-V integration services and restart the virtual machine. You will have the virtual NIC working.

Alternative if you really cannot install the Service Pack 2, you can manually install the driver from the integration services ISO using the device manager (`devmgmt.msc`), but this is not recommended.

Comment: done it and it is working as intended. Thank you for your help Ricardo.

Comment: @Richardo: Nice catch!